# VBA in Excel to search for string over multiple tabs and return locations

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have formed the code to do the searching the problem is trying to get it to find the multiple results. Currently it will return the first location of the string on each tab but then moves on. When I implement the While loop currently commented out it appears to find the first result and then escape the loop.

I'm not sure if there is a quirk to VBA loops that I am missing or my while check is not quite right but I have tried to debug by breaking it down and using message boxes but to no avail besides narrowing where I believe the issue to be in the while loop code.

```
Public Function GetSearchArray(strSearch As String) As String
Dim strResults As String
Dim SHT As Worksheet
Dim rFND As Range
Dim sFirstAddress As Range
For Each SHT In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    'MsgBox "Looping over worksheets"
    Set rFND = Nothing

    With SHT.UsedRange
        'MsgBox "Searching for" & strSearch

        Set rFND = .Cells.Find(What:="*" & strSearch & "*", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not rFND Is Nothing Then

            'Save first result so we can exit the loop
            If sFirstAddress Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "We have a result and sFirstAddress is nothing"
                Set sFirstAddress = rFND
            End If


            'Need to loop within the sheet to keep finding results
            'While (Not rFND Is Nothing) And rFND <> sFirstAddress

                'Deal with the results and build a string
                If strResults = "" Then
                    'MsgBox "No prev results"
                    strResults = "Worksheet(" & SHT.Index & ").Range(" & Chr(34) & rFND.Address & Chr(34) & ")"
                    MsgBox "First result " & strResults
                Else
                    strResults = strResults & "|" & "Worksheet(" & SHT.Index & ").Range(" & Chr(34) & rFND.Address & Chr(34) & ")"
                    MsgBox strResults
                End If

                Set rFND = .FindNext(rFND)


           'Wend

        End If
    End With
MsgBox "End sheet loop.."
Next
MsgBox "Finished going over sheets"
MsgBox strResults
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Public Function GetSearchArray(strSearch As String) As String

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim strFirst As String
    Dim strWSname As String

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        Set rngFound = ws.UsedRange.Find(strSearch, ws.UsedRange.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlPart)
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            strWSname = ws.Name
            If InStr(1, ws.Name, " ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then strWSname = "'" & strWSname & "'"
            strFirst = rngFound.Address
            Do
                GetSearchArray = GetSearchArray & "|" & strWSname & "!" & rngFound.Address
                Set rngFound = ws.UsedRange.Find(strSearch, rngFound, xlValues, xlPart)
            Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
        End If
    Next ws

    If Len(GetSearchArray) > 0 Then GetSearchArray = Mid(GetSearchArray, 2)

End Function
```

Then to call the function, use something like this:

```
Sub tgr()

    MsgBox Replace(GetSearchArray("test"), "|", Chr(10))

End Sub
```

Comment: This works exactly as I want. One extension - how would I call it from a cell and get the output back into the cell? I've tried a second function calling your re-write but it's not working.

Comment: In a cell: `=GetSearchArray("test")` If you wanted the results to be delimited with something other than "|", you could use Substitue, like: `=SUBSTITUTE(GetSearchArray("test"),"|",", ")`

Comment: Hmm I tried that but the cell just errors and shows #VALUE!

Comment: I have tried making sure that it is an array formula by pressing Ctr + Shift + Enter but no luck.

Comment: Turns out you can't use the `Range.FindNext` method in a UDF which is what was causing the problem. I used an alternative with the `Range.Find` method and it then tested successfully for me.  See updated Answer

Comment: Works for me now. Thank you, appreciate the effort. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop back to the `Set rFND = .Cells.Find(What:="*" & strSearch & "*", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)` line before your code reaches the `While` loop, currently that doesn't happen and rFND **always** equals sFirstAddress.

I am not sure of the most efficient way to store your address results and then check them as you loop, but I am sure someone can help you with that last part. I suspect it will be to store each result in an array and check each new result against the array until no new results are found, then move to the next sheet.

You'll probably also have to change your Find command to start at the last found result, if it starts in the same place each time I think it will find the same result over and over again. I am not sure, I haven't used Find much.

Comment: No? The While loop would be completely skipped. The `(Not rFND Is Nothing)` part would be satisfied, but the `rFND <> sFirstAddress` would not be. You used `And` in between them, so because both are not satisfied, it goes straight to WEnd and continues on.

Comment: Ha sorry, your infinite loop question disappeared, you must have figured it out :)

Comment: Sorry I realised my comment wasn't correct so deleted it. As you said. :)

Comment: I think I will change how the code is working. In a previous iteration I was just finding the count of the appearances in a sheet. I think I will incorporate this to then call find x number of times instead of the above while loop.

Comment: Seems like that could work. Good luck! Sorry no one told you an efficient way to do it yet. When you change your question I would suggest leaving the old code and putting your new trial underneath in case someone can make a While loop work better than a Count loop.